# How to make login form in node.js using mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

I am new in node.js and i want to make a login page using express and mysql database,Please share with me your idea with example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please see this tutorials.It's good for beginners.

http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

To connect mysql with node js http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql/mysql-cluster-with-node-js tutorial will be useful

Comment: Thanx buddy[Amila Iddamalgoda].. you solve my problem... i geeting my point.

Comment: Glad to help you out friend :)

Comment: The first link is dead.